# What causes high Send Request Times?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I've been looking at my app's performance and I noticed relatively high Send Request Times.

[image]

If I got it right the Send Request time includes the network trip of the payload from the client to the server + the server's processing time ([AppInsights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-javascript)).

Looking at the page load time I'm confused because the ajax call is taking ~300ms while, but the page loads in 4.27s. AppInsights is missing the server response graph for some reason (I have two websites in the same web app and for one I see server side telemetry, but for this one it's missing).

I don't see high resource consumption on the web app so I'm not really getting what's taking the almost 4 seconds in the request.

[image]

Is there a way to dig further?

Answer (score 0):

To find out which part of the application is causing slowness, you can collect *.Net profiling traces* during the time of issue, which will help to get the complete traces of application and its thread which are running on the app service plan instance during the time of issue, by analyzing the report generated by traces you can easily identify what is causing the issue.

Following are the steps to collect .Net Profiler traces:

1. Login to [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com).
2. Select the Azure Web App that you intend to troubleshoot
3. Click on **Diagnose and solve problems** > **Diagnostic Tools** > **Profiler**.
4. Once Collect .NET Profiler Trace tab is opened kindly click on
   **Collect Profiler Trace** button to collect profiling traces. As shown
   below.

After Collecting the Profiling traces, it will be generating the report as shown below which will help you in understanding cause slowness.

Further Clicking on Details Button it will be opening call stack with details.

Please find below link for more information:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2018/09/24/announcing-the-new-app-service-diagnostics-experience/